# spark dataframe transform JSON to ORC meet "column ambigous exception"

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I am using spark data frame, read JSON data, then save it to orc.
the code is very simple:

```
DataFrame json = sqlContext.read().json(input);

json.write().format("orc").save(output);
```

the job failed. what's wrong with this exception? Thanks.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'Canonical_URL' is ambiguous, could be: Canonical_URL#960, Canonical_URL#1010.;
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:279)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:116)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$16.apply(Analyzer.scala:350)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$16.apply(Analyzer.scala:350)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:350)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$8$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:341)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:285)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:123)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:122)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:127)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:341)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:243)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:285)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:243)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:242)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:61)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:933)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(SQLContext.scala:931)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.(DataFrame.scala:131)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(commands.scala:132)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:68)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:87)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:950)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:950)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:336)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:144)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:135)
>       at com.es.infrastructure.spark.orc.transformer.JsonTransformer.run(JsonTransformer.java:22)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:70)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Comment: I resolved this issue, because my json dataset has duplicate keys

Answer (score 1):

key must be with same name. While creating df and making some joins you need to drop one of key.